# How should I reorganise nine for-loops to something which generates an iterator or collection?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm taking my first steps in to Scala. I have a method which generates all points on a cube with a certain radius and a certain number of subdivisions ("segments"), then calls a function for each generated coordinate.

Ideally, instead, this routine would create an iterator/collection of some sort which I can map later. Without writing a mutable list which I append to then return, otherwise keeping this routine the same, I'm not really sure where to start.

Is somebody able to lead me by example and show me what a "good" implementation of the following would look like?

```
def pointsOnCube(radius: Float, segments: Int, callback: (Float, Float, Float) => Unit): Unit = {
  val mult = radius / segments

  // Generate points on the left and right faces (where x = radius/-radius)
  for (x <- Array(-1, 1)) {
    for (y <- -segments to segments) {
      for (z <- -segments to segments) {
        callback(x*radius, y*mult, z*mult)
      }
    }
  }

  // Generate points on the top and bottom faces (where y = radius/-radius)
  for (y <- Array(-1, 1)) {
    for (x <- -segments to segments) {
      for (z <- -segments to segments) {
        callback(x*mult, y*radius, z*mult)
      }
    }
  }

  // Generate points on the front and back faces (where z = radius/-radius)
  for (z <- Array(-1, 1)) {
    for (x <- -segments to segments) {
      for (y <- -segments to segments) {
        callback(x*mult, y*mult, z*radius)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To clarify (hopefully - you tell me!) I believe the ideal method signature would be:

```
def pointsOnCube(radius: Float, segments: Int): Seq[(Float, Float, Float)] = { ... }
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers you can give :)

Edit: Updated the method... this time I actually used it in my program and tested it before posting ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the application of some inner helper functions, and changing those nested for-loops into comprehension, you can pretty significantly shorten the code, and get the type signature you want out of it.

The code to generate the points on a side is identical - only the transformation of the values needs to change. You can pull that out into a helper function, and pass along a higher-order-function that specifies what you need to do with the results to get it into the proper state.

```
def pointsOnCube(radius: Float, segments: Int) = {
  val mult = radius / segments

  def getSide(f: (Float, Float, Float) => (Float, Float, Float)) = 
    for { a <- Array(-1, 1)
          b <- (-segments to segments)
          c <- (-segments to segments)
        } yield f(a, b, c)

  var leftRight = getSide { case(x, y, z) => (x*radius, y*mult, z*mult) }
  var topBottom = getSide { case(y, x, z) => (x*mult, y*radius, z*mult) }
  var frontBack = getSide { case(z, x, y) => (x*mult, y*mult, z*radius) }

  Seq(leftRight, topBottom, frontBack).flatten
}
```

Comment: I really like this, actually. The first option. It isn't quite right - although it creates a [very cool pattern](http://i.imgur.com/lhsB8pK.png) on my sphere - but switching the cases at the end fixes that up. The final method in it's entirety: http://pastebin.com/MW3A9MYc

Comment: @ledneb Didn't even notice the `(z,x,y)` shift at the end there. Glad to see that the general solution was easily updated to work though (and thanks for editing the answer to make it valid!)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using for comprehensions?

The following code is basically the same as yours, except I have removed the callback and collect the results of each of the three for loops together and return them using a tuple.  The first element being left and right faces, then top and bottom and lastly the front and back faces.

```
def pointsOnCube(radius: Float, segments: Int) = {
  val segments = 10
  val mult = radius / segments
  val segs = segments / 2

  (
    for {
      x <- Array(-1,1)
      y <- -segs to segs
      z <- -segs to segs
    } yield (x*radius,y*mult, z*mult),
    for {
      y <- Array(-1,1)
      x <- -segs to segs
      z <- -segs to segs
    } yield (x*mult,y*radius, z*mult),
    for {
      z <- Array(-1,1)
      x <- -segs to segs
      y <- -segs to segs
    } yield (x*mult,y*mult, z*radius)
  )
}


pointsOnCube(2,4)
```

Comment: I suppose OP's main point is to have one comprehension instead of 3 which are very similar to one another.

Comment: @EndeNeu the original question was about avoiding the callback and not using mutable lists, which all three current answers achieve.  Currently the other compactions, while worthy currently do not give the same result as they reuse the same values for x,y,z.. where the original code does not.

Comment: @ChrisK Can you clarify that? As I'm reading it, the original will generate the exact same values for x,y,z each time it goes through the for-comprehension, the only difference is the multiplier that gets applied. Or are you talking about how yours returns `(Array[(Float, Float, Float)], Array[(Float, Float, Float)], Array[(Float, Float, Float)])` instead of compressing it to a single `Seq[(Float, Float, Float)]` list?

Comment: @KChaloux no, look at the assignments for x,y,z in each for the for loops of the original code in the question.  They are not all the same.  The first one uses x <- Array(-1,1) but the second is x <- -segments to segments.

Comment: @ChrisK That's actually quite a good catch - didn't notice it at all. Have a +1.